# Is this valid PHP syntax?

Tags: php, programming-languages, syntax, conditional-statements

```
if ($var == ($var1 || $var2))
{
    ...
}
```

I am considering using this, but am ont sure if it is valid, and there doesn't seem to be somewhere to check.
It seems logically consistent to me but am not sure, and I don't have something to test it on close by.
If it is valid, what other mainstream languages support this sort of construct.

EDIT: The comparison is valid, but not in the way I was thinking.
What I was trying to do was actually the in_array() function, which I just discovered.

Comment: *(tipp)* Running `php -l file.php` will lint your php file and notify you of any errors.

Comment: @Daniel That doesn't necessarily mean it'd be easy to determine what it was doing.  I was expecting to answer this question with `php -l file.php`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is syntactical valid but semantical probably not what you wanted.

Because `$var1 || $var2` is a [boolean expression](http://php.net/language.operators.logical) and always yields *true* or *false*. And then `$var` is compared to the result of that boolean expression. So `$var` is always compared to either *true* or *false* and not to `$var1` or `$var2` (that’s what you’re have probably expected). So it’s not a shorthand to `($var == $var1) || ($var == $var2)`.

Now as you already noted yourself, [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) is a solution to this problem if you don’t want to write expressions like `($var == $var1) || ($var == $var2)`, especially when you have an arbitrary number of values you want to compare to:

```
in_array($var, array($var1, $var2))
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
($var == $var1) || ($var == $var2)
```

If you need a [strict comparison](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) (using `===` rather than `==`), set the third parameter to *true*:

```
in_array($var, array($var1, $var2), true)
```

Which is now equivalent to:

```
($var === $var1) || ($var === $var2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the corrected version is valid syntax:

```
if ($var == ($var1 || $var2))
```

Question is, what does it mean?

It will compare the result of the expression `($var1 || $var2)` which will be a boolean, to the value of `$var`.

And, as mentioned, `php -l file.php` will tell you if there are any syntax errors.

Edit:

Consider this:

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;

echo var_dump(($var1 || $var2));
```

Result is:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: @chustar Yes, it is valid.  But it is not the same as `if($var == $var1 || $var == $var2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command php -l filename.php from the command line to check for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

As George Marian says, it's missing a closing parenthesis so would throw a syntax error. It's otherwise valid, though, so I can't see that it's the logical OR construct itself that you're unsure about. It's used in several languages, including javascript.

Answer (score 0):

your corrected example is valid and will be TRUE is $var is TRUE and either $var1 or $var2 is TRUE .. OR . if $var, $var1 and $var2 are all FALSE